# Cannot access USB files

Tags: windows-10, file-permissions

Someone asked this a year or so ago but no resolution was published. I've tried to recover a 14.5GB drive but I've run into some trouble. The drive is already formatted FAT32. This happened after reinstalling Windows 10 Pro after an OS crash. There is no `Windows.old` folder due to the crash requiring completely new install.

When trying to open a file on the drive when logged into my normal (Admin) user, I get an error saying I do not have *Everyone* permissions via the Security tab on disk Properties. The problem is, there's no Security tab on in properties (only General, Tools, Hardware, Sharing, Customize). I can add permissions to sharing, but that does not give me access either.

That being said, I am able to access the drive with no problems using the windows Administrator user. New saved files work fine. I also tried taking ownership via command prompt on the Administrator user

```
takeown /F <path> /r /d y
```

but I get the message:

> ERROR: File ownership cannot be applied on insecure file systems; there is no support for ACLs

This happens when using the local admin account too. I've tried using the `icacls`-command as well, but with no luck. I also tried utilities to take ownership.

Copying the files also fails with a message

> You require permission from Everyone to make changes to this file.

Any ideas? I'm pulling my hair out over this one! Thanks in advance

Comment: Two things you can try: 1) Install Unlocker (here: http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/) and unlock this folder/drive, so you can do pretty much anything you want with it; 2) "Burn" a Linux ISO onto a USB flash drive, boot from it, access the drive in question, and change whatever permissions you have to change while it's accessible and mounted, but offline, because not in use by Windows.